# painterResource for null IDs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a list of images and a variable with can be anything from -1 to 13.
But the list contains only 3 indexes, so I have set a condition.

```
items[if(myInt == null) R.drawable.placholder else myInt
```

But it crashes my app with this **error**,

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
```

**My Code**

```
val items = listOf(R.drawable.red, R.drawable.green, R.drawable.blue)
Image(painter = painterResource(items[if(myInt==null) R.drawable.placholder else myInt]), contentDescription = null)
```

Comment: What's the error that you are getting ? the word just `crashes` cannot help to solve it

Comment: What type of error are you getting?  Index out of bounds?

Comment: I'm getting this ```java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4```

Comment: Right... so 4 isn't a valid index for a list of 3 items.  Only 0, 1, or 2

Comment: So how to add a condition that if it is out of list then add different image

Comment: @ABINASHKUMAR see my updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest solution is using kotlin [getOrElse](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-else.html). You can specify `-1` instead of `null`:

```
items.getOrElse(myInt ?: -1) { failedIndex -> R.drawable.ic_undo }
```

A more detailed solution is to check if `item.indices` contains your index:

```
if (myInt != null && items.indices.contains(myInt)) {
    items[myInt]
} else {
    R.drawable.ic_undo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Kotlin documentation, the correct way to access items in a list is by one of the methods below:

```
val list = listOf('a', 'b', 'c')
println(list.size) // 3
println("list.contains('a') is ${list.contains('a')}") // true
println(list.indexOf('b')) // 1
println(list[2]) // c
```

So, if your myInt var is anything but 0, 1, 2, or null and R.drawable.placholder returns anything but 0, 1, or 2, you will get an index out of bounds exception.

You might try something like this:

```
val items = listOf(R.drawable.red, R.drawable.green, R.drawable.blue)

var item = 0
if(myInt != null && items.contains(myInt)){
    item = myInt
}else{
    item = R.drawable.placholder
}

Image(painter = painterResource(item),contentDescription = null)
```

Comment: same error not working